# Creating objects on-the-fly in OCaml

Tags: oop, functional-programming, ocaml

I am attempting to learn OCaml by using compiled code instead of the top-level; however, much of the sample code online seems to appeal to the latter.

I would like to create a new Foo within a method of an object per below. This code does not compile, citing a syntax error with the doFooProc definition.

```
class bar =
object (self)
 method doFooProc = (new Foo "test")#process
end;;

class foo (param1:string)=
object (self)
 method process = Printf.printf "%s\n" "Processing!"
 initializer Printf.printf "Initializing with param = %s\n" param1
end;;
```

Additionally, the "let" syntax don't seem to be friendly within class definitions. Why is that?

```
class bar =
object (self)
 method doFooProc = 
  let xxx = (new Foo "test");
  xxx#process
end;;

class foo (param1:string)=
object (self)
 method process = Printf.printf "%s\n" "Processing!"
 initializer Printf.printf "Initializing with param = %s\n" param1
end;;
```

How do I go about creating a new object of class foo in the doFooProc method and call the instantiated foo's process command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mostly correct, but are either confusing syntax with the module system, or thinking of other languages. Take my considerations and you should be good!

> I would like to create a new Foo
>   within a method of an object per
>   below. This code does not compile,
>   citing a syntax error with the
>   doFooProc definition.

Lowercase "foo" for objects, modules are uppercase. Also, you must put the definition of foo above the object that calls it. You should get an `Unbound class foo` if this happens.

```
class bar =
object (self)
 method doFooProc = (new foo "test")#process
end;;
```

> Additionally, the "let" syntax don't seem to be friendly within class definitions. Why is that?

Because you don't have a matching `in`, instead you have a semi-colon. Then it will work. Also, you can remove those extra parens, but it doesn't matter.

```
class bar =
object (self)
 method doFooProc = 
  let xxx = (new Foo "test") in
  xxx#process
end;;
```

> If, say, a method in foo instantiated
>   a bar as well, is there any way to
>   escape the problem that arises with
>   ordering the class definitions within
>   the source file?

Yes. It's just like writing mutually recursive functions and modules, you connect them with the `and` keyword.

```
class bar =
  object (self)
    method doFooProc = (new foo "test")#process
  end

and foo (param1:string) = 
  object (self)
    method process = Printf.printf "%s\n" "Processing!"
    initializer Printf.printf "Initializing with param = %s\n" param1
  end
```

Comment: You're exactly right. I got into the habit of using capitalization for class names per some other languages and keep reverting to that with OCaml. Thanks!

Comment: eah. just to be clear. you can take that intuition when referring to modules and other files (since they are implicit modules)

Comment: If, say, a method in foo instantiated a bar as well, is there any way to escape the problem that arises with ordering the class definitions within the source file?

Answer (score 2):

For two mutually recursive class, use the and keyword

```
class bar =
  object (self)
    method doFooProc = 
      let xxx = (new foo "test") in
      xxx#process
  end
and foo (param1:string)=
  object (self)
    method process = Printf.printf "%s\n" "Processing!"
    initializer Printf.printf "Initializing with param = %s\n" param1
    method bar = new bar
  end;;`
```

Comment: wasn't sure if that worked with the class keyword, and didn't have time to check right now. correct.